# Why does Inno Setup ignore DefaultDirName

Tags: inno-setup

Running Inno Setup 5.5.6.  I corrected an error in my **DefaultDirName** value, but no matter what I do, the program continues to try to install in the old, erroneous location.  Even when I set it to a value matching one of the examples:

```
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
```

the program continues to choose the old, incorrect path.

How do I get Inno to use the corrected **DefaultDirName**?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the previous install went to the wrong destination directory, the install did complete.  According to the documentation for [DefaultDirName](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_defaultdirname):

> If **UsePreviousAppDir** is yes (the default) and Setup finds a previous
>   version of the same application is already installed, it will
>   substitute the default directory name with the directory selected
>   previously.

So my previous installation was overriding the new **DefaultDirName**. Once I uninstalled the program and re-ran the installer, it began using my corrected **DefaultDirName**.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`AppendDefaultDirName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_appenddefaultdirname.htm) directive to `no`, e.g.:

```
[Setup]
...
AppendDefaultDirName=no
```

As the reference says (emphasized by me):

> **By default**, when a folder in the dialog displayed by the Browse...
>   button on the Select Destination Location wizard page is clicked,
>   **Setup automatically appends the last component of DefaultDirName onto
>   the new path**.
>
> For example, if DefaultDirName is {pf}\My Program and "Z:\" is clicked, the new path will become "Z:\My Program".
>
> **Setting this directive to no disables the aforementioned behavior**. In
>   addition, it causes a Make New Folder button to appear on the dialog.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question, which was why the DefaultDirName was being ignored when I re-installed a program. The answer is that UsePreviousAppDir (which was Yes) overrides DefualtDirName.